# Sort a list of numbers in different representations with a macro in l3

Tags: macros, latex3, xint

I want to use a macro to sort numbers that have different representations. For example 3.5%, 0.321, 17/5, ...
If possible, the output of the sorted list should be in the same format again, or 17/5 should be in \frac{17}{5} format.

Unfortunately, my knowledge is not enough, so I wanted to ask for help and tips.

With my previous attempt, the numbers can already be sorted. But not yet in the different formats.
Using xint, I can also get the representation: 17/5 -> \frac{17}{5}, but then I can not sort the list anymore.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp,xintexpr}
\sisetup{group-separator={\,},output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \Sortiere } { s m }
 {
   \clist_set:Nn  \l_sort_clist  { #2 }
   \clist_sort:Nn \l_sort_clist
   {
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     { \fp_compare:nNnTF { \fp_eval:n{ ##1 } } < { \fp_eval:n{ ##2 } }
                            { \sort_return_swapped: }
                            { \sort_return_same: }
     }
     { \fp_compare:nNnTF { \fp_eval:n{ ##1 } } > { \fp_eval:n{ ##2 } }
                            { \sort_return_swapped: }
                            { \sort_return_same: }
     }
   }
%  \seq_new:N \l__thomas_A_seq
%  \seq_clear:N \l__thomas_A_seq
%  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
%   { \seq_put_right:Nx \l__thomas_A_seq
%     { \ensuremath { \xintSignedFrac{\xintIrr { \fp_eval:n { ##1 } } } } }
%   }
%   \seq_use:Nn \l__thomas_A_seq {;\,}
   \{\l_sort_clist\}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\Sortiere{1,12,9/5,7.12,-3,-5,2,7,11}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you provided? The output is sorted correctly and the representation isn't changed.

Comment: @Skillmon there is no 0.231%  in the input and in the output. And I want to have \frac{a}{b} in the output instead of a/b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho you should separate the values and the representation. And you can use a simple integer sequence to do the sorting and then apply this sorting to other sequences (I used fruits and quantities as it is imho easier to understand if the sequences contains differents things):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_th_fruit_seq
\seq_new:N \l_th_fruit_sorted_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn\l_th_fruit_seq {apples,pears,pineapples,bananas}

\seq_new:N \l_th_fruitqty_seq
\seq_new:N \l_th_fruitqty_sorted_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn\l_th_fruitqty_seq  {10,5,20,2}

\int_zero:N\l_tmpa_int
\seq_clear:N\l_tmpa_seq
\seq_map_inline:Nn\l_th_fruit_seq % a temporary seq with 1,2,3,4 for the sorting
 {
  \int_incr:N\l_tmpa_int
  \seq_put_right:NV\l_tmpa_seq {\l_tmpa_int}
 }

\seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_seq %sort over the quantity
 {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_item:Nn\l_th_fruitqty_seq {#1} } > { \seq_item:Nn\l_th_fruitqty_seq {#2} }
   { \sort_return_swapped: }
   { \sort_return_same:    }
 }

\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq  %apply the sorting to the seqs:
{
 \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_fruit_sorted_seq    { \seq_item:Nn   \l_th_fruit_seq{#1} }
 \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_fruitqty_sorted_seq { \seq_item:Nn \l_th_fruitqty_seq{#1}}
}

Sorted~fruits:~\seq_use:Nn\l_th_fruit_sorted_seq {,~}
\par
Quantities:~\seq_use:Nn \l_th_fruitqty_sorted_seq {,~}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: -@UlrikeFischer very nice, thank you

Comment: -@Ulrike Fischer, I think your idea is great, because it is very general. However, I have now found a solution that works with some replacements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose the following which I derived from your own answer, I dropped one or two options because anyhow I don't know xparse syntax.

I have limited knowledge of expl3, so there might be sub-optimal things.

Here is the idea: only xint can handle exactly fractions (beyond a certain size), and only fpeval knows logarithms etc... currently. So simply parse the input, and if there is a `/` sign, assume this is some fraction and parse it via `\xintthexpr` to allow some expression (needed for my example below); if there is no `/` parse the numerical input via `fpeval`.

Then do all the comparison test using xint routines, because they will accept as input the output of `\fpeval`.

We keep the original input for final printing, except that (in current version of code) any `/` as explained above will trigger an `\xinttheexpr` computation.

Of course this approach breaks on `ln(2)/2`, but it would not be hard for someone (not me) knowing xparse and expl3 and regex to trigger `\fpeval` then.

In short, do the maximum of computations with `\fpeval` but do all comparisons with `xint` because it allows arbitrarily large fractions.

For simplification I dropped all the code detecting if `\num` could be used to format output, but again, easy to add (I don't know siunitx either !)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp,xintexpr}
\sisetup{group-separator={\,},output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\clist_new:N \l_T_printnumbers_clist
\tl_new:N \l_T_parsedinput_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{ \Sortiere }{ O{} t> t! m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { thomas/Sortiere } { #1 }
  \tl_clear:N \l_T_parsedinput_tl
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #4 }
       { 
          \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 }
% FIXING THE REGEX FOR \%
          \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{\%} } { /100 } \l_tmpa_tl
% (debugging) \show\l_tmpa_tl
          \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{ln} } { ln } \l_tmpa_tl
% (debugging) \show\l_tmpa_tl
         \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{sqrt} } { sqrt } \l_tmpa_tl
          % notice here ##1 is tested so a /100 from a \% will be still be fp_evaluated
          \regex_match:nnTF { .*/.* } { ##1 } 
             {
               \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \xinttheexpr ##1 \relax }
               \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { 
                                       { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl } 
                                       { \exp_not:N \xintSignedFrac 
                                                    { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl }
                                       }
                                     }
             }
             {
               \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { 
                                       { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } }
                                       { \exp_not:n { ##1 } } 
                                     }
             }
          \tl_put_right:Nx \l_T_parsedinput_tl { { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl } }
        }
   {
  %\show\l_T_parsedinput_tl
  \tl_sort:Nn \l_T_parsedinput_tl
   {
     \IfBooleanTF{#2}
       { \xintifLt { \use_i:nn ##1 } { \use_i:nn ##2 } }
       { \xintifGt { \use_i:nn ##1 } { \use_i:nn ##2 } }
         { \sort_return_swapped: }
         { \sort_return_same: }
   }
  \clist_clear:N \l_T_printnumbers_clist
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_T_parsedinput_tl
    { 
        \clist_put_right:Nn \l_T_printnumbers_clist { \use_ii:nn ##1 }
    }
   \IfBooleanTF{#2}
    { \clist_use:Nnnn \l_T_printnumbers_clist { \,\ensuremath { \geq }\, }{ \,\ensuremath { \geq }\, }{ \,\ensuremath { \geq }\, } }
    { \clist_use:Nnnn \l_T_printnumbers_clist { \,\ensuremath { \leq }\, }{ \,\ensuremath { \leq }\, }{ \,\ensuremath { \leq }\, } }
    }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { thomas/Sortiere }
 {
  unsort .bool_set:N = \l__T_Sortiere_unsort_bool,   
  unsort .initial:n  = false,                              % Starteinstellung 
  unsort .default:n  = true,                               % 
  round  .int_set:N = \l__thomas_sortiere_round_int,       % IGNORED
  round  .initial:n = 4,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot}

\begin{document}

\[  \Sortiere{10, 101/10, 10.015, 3*34} \]

\[ \Sortiere{2^4, 4^2, 3^2, 5^{0.5}, 13, 25-1, \ln(17)} \]

\[ \Sortiere>!{2^4, 4^2, 3^2, 5^{0.5}, 13, 25-1, \ln(17)} \]

\[ \Sortiere{1.5\%,1,12,9/5,7.12,-3e1,-5,2,\sqrt{8}} \]

\[ \Sortiere{46296296/123456789, 370370371/987654320, (370370371/987654320 + 46296296/123456789)/2}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (I had to change the regex for `\%` compared to OP, I had problems otherwise)

Comment: I thing the good approach would be to parse input for `\frac{...}{..}`, replace such things by `((...)/(...))` and choose the `\xintthexpr` branch. Only if such a `\frac` is  found would `xintttheexpr` branch for evaluation taken.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried last.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp,xintexpr}
\sisetup{group-separator={\,},output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{ \Sortiere }{ O{} t> t! m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { thomas/Sortiere } { #1 }
  \clist_set:Nn \l_T_numberlist_clist { #4 }
  \clist_set:Nn \l_T_number_unsort_clist { #4 }
   \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_T_number_unsort_clist { \% } { /100 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{ln} } { ln } \l_T_number_unsort_clist
   \bool_if:NTF \l__T_Sortiere_unsort_bool
   {
     \clist_clear:N \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist
     \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_T_number_unsort_clist
       { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist { \ensuremath { ##1 } } }
       \ensuremath {
          \regex_replace_all:nnN { /100 } { \c{num}\cB\{ \1\cE\}\c{,}\c{\%} } \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist
          \regex_replace_all:nnN { ln } { \c{ln} } \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist
          \regex_replace_all:nnN { [+-]?\d+/[+-]?\d+ } { \c{xintSignedFrac} \cB\{ \0\cE\} } \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist
          \regex_replace_all:nnN { [+-]?\d+e[+-]?\d+ } { \c{num} \cB\{ \0\cE\} } \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist
          \regex_replace_all:nnN { \. } { , } \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist
          \regex_replace_all:nnN { (sqrt)(\{[+-]?\d+\}) } { \c{sqrt} \cB\{ \2\cE\} } \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist   
      \left\{ \clist_use:Nnnn \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist { ;\, }{ ;\, }{ ;\, } \right\}
   }
   }
   {
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_T_numberlist_clist { \% } { /100 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{ln} } { ln } \l_T_numberlist_clist
  \clist_sort:Nn \l_T_numberlist_clist
   {
     \IfBooleanTF{#2}
       { \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 < ##2 } }
       { \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 > ##2 } }
         { \sort_return_swapped: }
         { \sort_return_same: }
   }
  \clist_clear:N \l_T_printnumbers_clist
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_T_numberlist_clist
    { \IfBooleanTF{#3}
       { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_T_printnumbers_clist { \ensuremath { ##1 } } }
       { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_T_printnumbers_clist { \ensuremath { \xintSignedFrac{ \xintIrr { \xinttheexpr round ( \fp_eval:n { ##1 } ,\l__thomas_sortiere_round_int ) \relax } } } } }
    }
   \IfBooleanTF{#3}{ 
                     \regex_replace_all:nnN { /100 } { \c{num}\cB\{ \1\cE\}\c{,}\c{\%} } \l_T_printnumbers_clist
                     \regex_replace_all:nnN { ln } { \c{ln} } \l_T_printnumbers_clist
                     \regex_replace_all:nnN { [+-]?\d+/[+-]?\d+ } { \c{xintSignedFrac} \cB\{ \0\cE\} } \l_T_printnumbers_clist
                     \regex_replace_all:nnN { [+-]?\d+e[+-]?\d+ } { \c{num} \cB\{ \0\cE\} } \l_T_printnumbers_clist
                     \regex_replace_all:nnN { \. } { , } \l_T_printnumbers_clist
                     \regex_replace_all:nnN { (sqrt)(\{[+-]?\d+\}) } { \c{sqrt} \cB\{ \2\cE\} } \l_T_printnumbers_clist
                   } 
                   { }
   \IfBooleanTF{#2}
    { \clist_use:Nnnn \l_T_printnumbers_clist { \,\ensuremath { \geq }\, }{ \,\ensuremath { \geq }\, }{ \,\ensuremath { \geq }\, } }
    { \clist_use:Nnnn \l_T_printnumbers_clist { \,\ensuremath { \leq }\, }{ \,\ensuremath { \leq }\, }{ \,\ensuremath { \leq }\, } }
    }
  \group_end:
 }
  \clist_new:N \l_T_printnumbers_clist
  \clist_new:N \l_T_numberlist_clist
  \clist_new:N \l_T_number_unsort_clist
  \clist_new:N \l_T_printnumbers_unsort_clist

\keys_define:nn { thomas/Sortiere }
 {
  unsort .bool_set:N = \l__T_Sortiere_unsort_bool,   
  unsort .initial:n  = false,                              % Starteinstellung 
  unsort .default:n  = true,                               % 
  round  .int_set:N = \l__thomas_sortiere_round_int,
  round  .initial:n = 4,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot}

\begin{document}

\[ \Sortiere[unsort]>{2^4, 4^2, 3^2, 5^{0.5}, 13, 25-1, ln(17)} \]

\[ \Sortiere>{2^4, 4^2, 3^2, 5^{0.5}, 13, 25-1, ln(17)} \]

\[ \Sortiere[round=12]>{2^4, 4^2, 3^2, 5^{0.5}, 13, 25-1, \ln(17)} \]

\[ \Sortiere>!{2^4, 4^2, 3^2, 5^{0.5}, 13, 25-1, \ln(17)} \]

\[ \Sortiere{1.5\%,1,12,9/5,7.12,-3e1,-5,2,sqrt{8}} \]

\[ \Sortiere[unsort]!{1.5\%,1,12,-11/5,7.12,-3e1,-5,2,sqrt{8}} \]

\end{document}
```