# Assignment of elements in different lists

Tags: macros, latex3

Assignment of elements in different lists

Using the self-defined macro `\CountLetter[optional](letters){Text}`, different letters in a text can be counted and displayed in a table with their numbers and relative frequencies (in this example only four).

The presentation should be ordered according to the number. This is done with `\seq_sort:Nn` (thanks again to Ulrike Fischer for her great answer here: [Sort a list of numbers in different representations with a macro in l3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405995/sort-a-list-of-numbers-in-different-representations-with-a-macro-in-l3))

The letters displayed in the table can be entered using the optional argument. As long as you enter these letters continuously from the beginning, the macro will work properly. But if you omit one or more letters, the assignment is no longer correct between the elements of the different lists.

In this much shortened form of the macros, I used only four letters, one after the other: a, b, c, d
The values of the counted letters are stored in 
`\l_thomas_Text_a_int`, `\l_thomas_Text_b_int`, `\l_thomas_Text_c_int`, and `\l_thomas_Text_d_int` and in this order given to a list

correct:        `\CountLetter(a)`

correct:        `\CountLetter(a,b)`

correct:        `\CountLetter(a,b,c)`

not correct:    `\CountLetter(b,c)`, because the first letter a is omit.

not correct:  `\CountLetter(a,c)`, because the second letter b is omit

My question is, how could I get an appropriate mapping for the case when letters are omitted/skipped?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=1.3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx,xintexpr,booktabs,kantlipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \int_new:N \l_thomas_Text_a_int
  \int_new:N \l_thomas_Text_b_int
  \int_new:N \l_thomas_Text_c_int
  \int_new:N \l_thomas_Text_d_int
  \int_new:N \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int

  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_sorted_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_qty_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_qty_sorted_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_relativQty_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_relativQty_sorted_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{ \CountLetter }{ O{} D(){a,b,c,d} m }
{
  \regex_count:nnN { [A-Za-z] } {  #3 }  \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int % Zählt alle Buchstaben
  \regex_count:nnN { a|A }      {  #3 }  \l_thomas_Text_a_int      % Zählt kleine und große a
  \regex_count:nnN { b|B }      {  #3 }  \l_thomas_Text_b_int      % Zählt kleine und große b
  \regex_count:nnN { c|C }      {  #3 }  \l_thomas_Text_c_int      % Zählt kleine und große c
  \regex_count:nnN { d|D }      {  #3 }  \l_thomas_Text_d_int      % Zählt kleine und große d

  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn\l_th_letter_seq { #2 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn\l_th_letter_qty_seq {
                                               \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_a_int },
                                               \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_b_int },
                                               \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_c_int },
                                               \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_d_int }
                                              }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn\l_th_letter_relativQty_seq
                          {
                            \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_a_int / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int },
                            \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_b_int / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int },
                            \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_c_int / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int },
                            \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_d_int / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int }
                          }

  \int_zero:N\l_tmpa_int
  \seq_clear:N\l_tmpa_seq

  \seq_map_inline:Nn\l_th_letter_seq % a temporary seq with 1,2,3,4 for the sorting
    {
     \int_incr:N\l_tmpa_int
     \seq_put_right:NV\l_tmpa_seq {\l_tmpa_int}
    }

  \seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_seq % sort over the quantity
    {
     \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_item:Nn\l_th_letter_qty_seq {##1} } < { \seq_item:Nn\l_th_letter_qty_seq {##2} }
     { \sort_return_swapped: }
     { \sort_return_same:    }
    }

  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq  % apply the sorting to the seqs:
    {
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_sorted_seq     { \seq_item:Nn  \l_th_letter_seq{##1}    }
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_qty_sorted_seq { \ensuremath { \seq_item:Nn  \l_th_letter_qty_seq{##1} } }
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_relativQty_sorted_seq
          { \ensuremath {
                         \xintFrac{ \xinttheexpr
                                      reduce( \seq_item:Nn  \l_th_letter_qty_seq{##1} / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int )
                                    \relax
                                  }
                        }
          }
    }

 \emph{#3}

 \par\bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{c *{\seq_count:N \l_th_letter_sorted_seq}{c}}     \toprule
    letter  & \seq_use:Nn \l_th_letter_sorted_seq {&}            \\ \midrule
    abs.~H. & \seq_use:Nn \l_th_letter_qty_sorted_seq {&}        \\ \midrule
    rel.~H. & \seq_use:Nn \l_th_letter_relativQty_sorted_seq {&} \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\def\LetterAll{ \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int } }
\def\LetterA{   \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_a_int } }
\def\LetterB{   \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_b_int } }
\def\LetterC{   \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_c_int } }
\def\LetterD{   \fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_d_int } }

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

%\CountLetter{\kant[3-4]}

\CountLetter(a,b,c,d){Das ist ein sinnloser Text ohne Hand und Fuß. Der Bärtige lachte höhnisch, Fußball war nie sein Über nnnnnnn  xxx Es war ein langer Tag, an dem es wieder einmal nur wenig zu Essen gab und die Hühner wurden auch nicht fett.}

\bigskip
In this text are \LetterA{} a's and \LetterAll{} letters overall.

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

After the answer of @Manuel, this is the complete code with vertical an horizontal table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=1.3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx,xfp,xintexpr,booktabs,kantlipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

  \int_new:N \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int

  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_sorted_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_qty_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_qty_sorted_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_relativQty_seq
  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_relativQty_sorted_seq

  \seq_new:N \l_th_letter_row_seq

  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN { xnc }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \CountLetter }{ O{} D(){a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,ä,ö,ü,ß} m }
{
\regex_count:nnN { [A-Za-z] } { #3 } \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_th_letter_seq { #2 }
\seq_clear:N \l_th_letter_qty_seq
\seq_clear:N \l_th_letter_relativQty_seq
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_th_letter_seq
 {
  \int_zero_new:c { l_thomas_Text_ \tl_to_str:n {##1} _int }
  \regex_count:xnc { \text_lowercase:n {##1} | \text_uppercase:n {##1} }
   { #3 } { l_thomas_Text_ \tl_to_str:n {##1} _int }
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_qty_seq
   { \fp_eval:n { \use:c{ l_thomas_Text_ \tl_to_str:n {##1} _int } } }
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_relativQty_seq
   { \fp_eval:n { \use:c { l_thomas_Text_ \tl_to_str:n {##1} _int } / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int } }
 }

\int_zero:N\l_tmpa_int
\seq_clear:N\l_tmpa_seq

\seq_map_inline:Nn\l_th_letter_seq % a temporary seq with 1,2,3,4 for the sorting
 {
  \int_incr:N\l_tmpa_int
  \seq_put_right:NV\l_tmpa_seq {\l_tmpa_int}
 }

\seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_seq %sort over the quantity
 {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_item:Nn\l_th_letter_qty_seq {##1} } < { \seq_item:Nn\l_th_letter_qty_seq {##2} }
   { \sort_return_swapped: }
   { \sort_return_same:    }
 }

\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq  % apply the sorting to the seqs:
{
 \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_sorted_seq     { \seq_item:Nn  \l_th_letter_seq{##1}    }
 \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_qty_sorted_seq { \ensuremath { \seq_item:Nn  \l_th_letter_qty_seq{##1} } }
 \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_relativQty_sorted_seq { \ensuremath { 
                    \xintFrac{ \xinttheexpr reduce( \seq_item:Nn  \l_th_letter_qty_seq{##1} / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int ) \relax } } }
}

\seq_clear:N \l_th_letter_row_seq
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
        {
         \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_row_seq
                          {
                             \seq_item:Nn \l_th_letter_seq{##1}
                              &
                             \seq_item:Nn \l_th_letter_qty_seq{##1}
                              &
%                            \ensuremath { \xintFrac{ \xinttheexpr reduce(
%                            \seq_item:Nn  \l_th_letter_qty_seq{##1} / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int
                            \seq_item:Nn \l_th_letter_relativQty_seq{##1} 
%                            ) \relax } }
                           }
         }

\emph{#3}
\par\bigskip
Buchstaben~nach~Häufigkeiten~sortiert:\\
\seq_use:Nn\l_th_letter_sorted_seq {,~}
\par
Quantities:\\
\seq_use:Nn \l_th_letter_qty_sorted_seq {,~}
\par
Gesamtzahl~aller~Buchstaben: ~\fp_eval:n { \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int }

\par\bigskip
{\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{c *{\seq_count:N \l_th_letter_sorted_seq}{c}}\toprule
letter  & \seq_use:Nn\l_th_letter_sorted_seq {&}     \\\midrule
abs.~H. & \seq_use:Nn \l_th_letter_qty_sorted_seq {&} \\\midrule
rel.~H. & \seq_use:Nn\l_th_letter_relativQty_sorted_seq {&} 
%\\\midrule
%Bla       & \seq_item:Nn \l_th_letter_relativQty_sorted_seq {2}
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}


\sisetup{
%table-number-alignment=left,
%table-figures-decimal =8,
round-mode=places,
round-precision=5
}
\par\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=1.5] }
 Buchstabe & {abs. H} & {rel. H.} \\ \midrule
\seq_use:Nn \l_th_letter_row_seq { \\ }
\end{tabular}

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

%\kant[3-4]

\CountLetter{Das ist ein sinnloser Text ohne Hand und Fuß. Er lachte höhnisch, Fußball war nie sein Über nnnnnnn  xxx Es war ein langer Tag, 
              an dem es wieder einmal nur wenig zu Essen gab und die Hühner wurden auch nicht fett.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment for now. I can't compile right now, but for the moment here are a few tips so you don't hardcode things

This way you do things not by hand, but through the argument

```
\regex_count:nnN { [A-Za-z] } { #3 } \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_th_letter_seq { #2 }
\seq_clear:N \l_th_letter_qty_seq
\seq_clear:N \l_th_letter_relativQty_seq
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_th_letter_seq
 {
  \int_zero_new:c { l_thomas_Text_ \tl_to_str:n {##1} _int }
  \regex_count:xnc { \text_lowercase:n {##1} | \text_uppercase:n {##1} }
   { #3 } { l_thomas_Text_ \tl_to_str:n {##1} _int }
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_qty_seq
   { \fp_eval:n { \use:c{ l_thomas_Text_ \tl_to_str:n {##1} _int } } }
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_th_letter_relativQty_seq
   { \fp_eval:n { \use:c { l_thomas_Text_ \tl_to_str:n {##1} _int } / \l_thomas_Text_ABCabc_int } }
 }
```

And you need from outside `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN { xnc }`.

Of the rest, remember that `\int_step_inline:` exists so that might optimize a bit, plus you might need to take precautions with expansion. Using `:x` arguments with `\ensuremath` inside, you might want to stop expansion `\exp_not:N \ensuremath` and may be there are more things.

Comment: yes I think this goes in the right direction, however, my knowledge is not so good that I have seen the exact way.

Comment: After declaring `\cs_generate_variant:` outside, try to put that code to substitute the beginning of your hardcoded things, that includes until you set `\l_th_letter_qty_seq` and `\l_th_letter_relativQty_seq`.

Comment: -@Manuel, this seems to solve the problem, phantastic. Thank you!

Comment: Do not accept yet, I think your code might be rewritten a little bit more, wait if someone comes and corrects many more things.

Comment: @Thomas Note that you do not need the huge list of `\int_new:` that you added in your edit, it's all taken care with `\int_zero_new:` inside the `\seq_map_inline:` of my code.